# How to optimize my query joining two tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My requirement is as below

> SQL1: sel Names, Numbers from Table1 where condition = FilterName

```
the output of this will be like:
    aa,11
    bb,22
     cc,33
```

SQL2:  I need to write a sql like this

```
 Sel * from table2 where condition = 'Something' 
         And names & Numbers in ([aa,11],[bb,22],[cc,33])
```

I have written the query like

```
Select * from table2 where condition = 'SOmething' 
         And names in (select Names from Table1 where condi = 'FilterName')
         And Numbers in (select Numbers from Table1 where condi = 'FilterName')
```

Is there any other better way to write this query? I cannot use procedure here

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say about it?

Comment: sorry. i was not able to post my complete question, As i replaced select with Sel and * with ALL i am able to post complete question now

Comment: How many rows will these tables typically contain?

Comment: we cant fix the number of rows returned .. can be 0 to thousand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my interpretation of the problem, something like this should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 t2
JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.Names = t2.names AND t1.Numbers = t2.numbers
WHERE t1.condi = 'FilterName'
AND t2.condition = 'Something'
```

MySQL does have syntax for `(a,b,c) IN ((a1,b1,c1),(a2,b2,c2)...)`, but I haven't yet found a way to use indexes with it, so it's not very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use JOINs here:

```
Select table2.* from table2
join table1 on table2.names = table1.names and table2.numbers = table1.numbers
where table1.condi = 'FilterName'
and table2.condition = 'Something'
```

I hope this helps!